# How do I get a assign a record value to a variable in Laravel 5.3?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I need to display all the vehicle records belonging to properties of the currenty logged on user.
Before I pass the data to the view I need to filter out all the properties except those owned by the current user id.

I have a relationship in the Vehicle model that performs the foreign key constraint.

```
public function propiedad(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Property', 'propiedad_id','id' );
}
```

My Controller is using this filter before passing the data to the view. I assume I have to acquire the property ids that belong to the user before I filter the vehicles that belong to those properties. This is where I am having trouble.

```
    $user_properties = array(?????);
    $Vehiculo = Vehiculo::where('propiedad_id', $user_properties);
```

Comment: How is the relation defined between vehicles and users?

Comment: Show your all relations like of user and property..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your properties table has a `user_id` column then on your user model define a `vehicles` `hasManyThrough` relationship like

```
public function vehicles()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Vehicle::class, Property::class);
}
```

Then in your controller you can do:

```
$users = User::with('vehicles')->get();
```

Or for a single user

```
$vehicles= User::find($id)->vehicles;
```